# Will console applications compiled on Windows work on Linux and MAC OS X using DOSBox?

Tags: c++

**The doubt**

I have written some code in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express as so:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    system("cls");

    char name[20];

    cout<<"\nEnter your name:";

    cin.getline(name,20);

    system("pause");

    cout<<"\nYour name is:"<<name;

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

And now I have compiled it and sent it to a friend on a Linux machine. he downloads the DOSBox software and then runs this program.

**THE DOUBT**

Will it run as it does on my machine or will this create any problem?

**why I am asking this?**

I recently downloaded a linux live cd and ran it on my machine. I can't install it on this machine as it is a shared PC. Anyway, I typed  `cls`  into the terminal and there was no response. I typed  `pause`  again there was no response. So it set me wondering if the command "cls" that i am passing to the system in the above code will really have any effect on a linux machine.

Comment: The `cls` and `pause` commands are special commands in the Windows command prompt. Few other systems have these.

Comment: Besides, you can't expect a program compiled for Windows to run on anything else than another Windows computer. If you want to run Windows program in Linux, see e.g. the [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) project.

Comment: DOSbox is for running DOS programs and you've made a windows program so it won't work at all.

Comment: even if i send the exe? @jcoder

Comment: @IcyFlame: A Windows .EXE will have a small DOS stub that prints the message "This program cannot be run in DOS mode.", or something similar. Just open your .EXE in Notepad to see this text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few reasons why this program won't work on other machines - I will summarise the two main ones:

1. You use system instructions which are not supported by other operating systems. If you attempt the run these instructions on a different OS, the OS will complain that it doesn't understand them and the program will crash.
2. (And probably more importantly,) the Windows executable you have created is a Windows `.exe` file which is [Microsoft's Portable Executable format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). Linux can only read executables in [ELF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), and Mac OS X uses the [Mach-O format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O).

These two points are worth discussion in their own right, and as Joachim pointed out in the comments, the WINE emulator is quite good at emulating a windows environment on Linux, so this may be an option for program compatibility.

**EDIT:** I should add here that Point 1 assumes that Point 2 has been overcome. Point 2 is the reason executables on one OS just plain "don't work" on other operating systems.

---

**Response to comment:**

Generally, yes, `ELF` files are the standard for all Linux distros (there may be a few rare exceptions). Similarly, `PE` files are the standard for all Windows versions. Provided you have a relatively up to date CPU, then if you compile an executable on one Linux distro, then it should work on others.

The exception here is, if you compile the program on a machine with a recent CPU, and wish to run it on a machine with a very old CPU, the old CPU may not support some of the instructions that the compiler creates. However, these days just compiling a program with the default settings generally works on all (Intel) CPUs. If you know for a fact that your target machine uses a very different or older CPU, you can add the [-march=...](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) compiler option so the compiler generates instructions that will definitely work on the target machine.

Finally, DOSBox is *not* a Windows Emulator, it is a DOS emulator. The two systems, despite their history, are quite different. DOSBox is not designed to run native Windows applications, it is designed to run native DOS applications (most of which are [abandonware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware) these days). If you'd like to run DOS programs on Linux such as [Dangerous Dave](http://www.dosgamesarchive.com/download/dangerous-dave/) (one of my nostalgic favourites), then you can. However, if you wish to run Windows applications, you will need an emulator designed for this purpose, such as [WINE](http://www.winehq.org).

For reference, DOS uses the obsolete [MZ Executable format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable).

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Pls clarify the following. Will an "elf" file work on a Linux exactly as an "EXE" file works in windows? Can we transfer an elf file from one distribution to other and it would still work? Just as we can run an EXE file on any windows version from 98 to XP? And if EXE files can't be run in dos as @MSalters said then what is DOSBox? How can we run an EXE file on a Linux machine using DOSBox?(I have done so myself and have also asked many friends to do this as it works).

Comment: That's alright, I've recently taken a great interest in executable formats - see additional edit for response to comment :)

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. To review, an EXE file can work on a Linux or mac only if it is either run in "WINE" emulator or a virtual machine running windows. Sir, but I have run EXE files on DOSBox both in windows 7 and Linux. If DOSBox does not emulate windows then how is this possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be honest - [this](http://www.dosbox.com/information.php?page=0) is DOSBox's official word on compatibility. Likely, the program you were running was compatible with the 286/386 system. [There appears to be some compatibility between DOS and `PE/COFF` executables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable), though I'm not sure how much. In any case the program must have used only DOS-compatible instructions.

Comment: Sir, I downloaded dangerous dave(Which i totally loved). It also has an "EXE" extension. So what is the difference between that and the exe that i have compiled?(If any...)

Comment: Ah, it's not the file extension (`.exe`) which defines the executable type, it's the internal structure of the file. Executables do not need to have any file extension (Mach-O files don't) but DOS and Windows use `.exe` as a hint to both the user and the OS that the file is an executable. The Dangerous Dave executable is no doubt an `MZ` executable, whereas gcc and other modern compilers only generate `PE` executables. [The "DOS Stub" section of this website](http://wiki.osdev.org/PE) explains why some `PE` (Windows) files work on DOSBox even though they are not strictly `MZ` executables.

Comment: That I exactly what I needed the answer. To review: a PE file can run on DOS but a MZ file will definitely not run in windows is that it?

Comment: Correct. It is possible (though not guaranteed) for a `PE` executable to run on DOS, but an `MZ` executable will not run on [any Windows version later than Windows '98](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable).

Comment: Does that mean in win 95 even an MZ executable will run?

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You have help me understand many things about executables.

Answer (score 0):

1. `pause` and `cls` most likely will not work directly in other OSes because these are Windows/DOS-specific commands.
2. If you remove the DOS-specific commands and make the program generic, then the EXE file built in Windows can most probably be executed in Linux or MacOS through Wine. Please see http://www.winehq.org/about/ and http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX . I'm saying "most probably" because you still need to try it out to see if there are problems.
3. If you run your EXE executable inside a virtualized environment running Windows in it like [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), then it will work.
4. On Linux, the command to clear the screen is `clear`. Is that what you're really intending to do?